# Why retention.ms of Kaka Streams repartition topic is set to -1 by default? Isn't this infinitely retain messages in repartition topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I think it's related to the below links, but I don't understand.

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6535
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6150
- [Kafka Streams deleting consumed repartition records, to reduce disk usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55182492/kafka-streams-deleting-consumed-repartition-records-to-reduce-disk-usage)

It's possible to provide topic configurations like "retention.ms", "cleanup.policy" for kafka streams internal topics like *-changelog topics to delete useless logs.

But when it comes to internal topics like *-repartition topics, it's not possible to provide topic configuration values, even though the default "retention.ms" for repartition topic is "-1" which means infinite retention. How can I delete or manage repartition topics? Otherwise the repartition topic's size is going to be too large and disk malfunction problems might occur.

How can I manage repartition topics? What is purgeData?
Couldn't find any related explanations on the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fact**

- `retention.ms` for the repartition topics is -1 by default and there's no way to override this value in kafka-streams client code.

**What I misunderstood**

- Size of the repartition topic would be increasing infinitely since the `retentions.ms` for the repartition topics is -1.

**Fix misunderstanding**

- There's a method called `maybeCommit` in the `StreamThread` class.
- `maybeCommit` method is called iteratively inside the loop that handles stream records.
- Inside the `maybeCommit` method (version 2.7.1), there's a comment like below.

  > try to purge the committed records for repartition topics if possible

  - https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.7.1/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/StreamThread.java#L923-L926
- Based on this, what I understand is that when the record in the repartition topics is streamed down to the changelog topic, then the records already sent are purged periodically.
- Therefore, there's no need to clear or manage `retention.ms` for the repartition topics.

**Reference**

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6150

Please leave a comment or correct this if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with ksqldb. Internal topics grew up like TB of data in a matter of days with infinite retention by default. We altered them setting retention.ms to some value instead of infinite (-1) but after that everything broke.
Today I executed this command:
`set topic.retention.ms=3600000`
After that, I created a table and all internal topics were created with retention.ms=1h instead of infinite.
Will try next week in prd environment to see if ksqldb (0.28.2) evicts segments and everything is ok.
Source: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#internal-topic-parameters
Hope it helps
Regards