# Retention period of internal kafka stream topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am having a use-case of kafka streams where I need to perform aggregate operation with past data that might be consumed even months earlier.

I wonder if it means that I need to be concerned about default retention period of internal topics e.g. `XXX-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-changelog`, `XXX-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-repartition` and explicitly change/set somehow?

If yes, is there a way to configure it for stream app? If I set default retention period at broker level, will my newly created internal topics have forever retention?

Comment: Seems to be similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65971984/why-retention-ms-of-kaka-streams-repartition-topic-is-set-to-1-by-default-isn

Comment: I think just the very final part of my question is similar to the question in link. The other 2 questions and use-case described have different angles to it.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that `XXX-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-changelog` topics have `cleanup.policy=compact`. Meaning the messages will never be deleted as log compaction is enabled. `XXX-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-repartition` topics have `retention.ms=-1` by default even if broker level default is set to any other value.