# retention.ms is set to -1 by sreams on reparation topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, topology

Kafka streams is creating a reparation topic in the kafka cluster with
Retention.ms=-1, I think because of this reason I am unable to consume the date from the topic.

Why it is creating with -1ms?
How to let it create with a custom ms?

Answer (score 0):

Fact

retention.ms for the repartition topics is -1 by default and there's no way to override this value in kafka-streams client code.
What I misunderstood

Size of the repartition topic would be increasing infinitely since the retentions.ms for the repartition topics is -1.
Fix misunderstanding

There's a method called maybeCommit in the StreamThread class.
maybeCommit method is called iteratively inside the loop that handles stream records.
Inside the maybeCommit method (version 2.7.1), there's a comment like below.
try to purge the committed records for repartition topics if possible

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.7.1/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/StreamThread.java#L923-L926
Based on this, what I understand is that when the record in the repartition topics is streamed down to the changelog topic, then the records already sent are purged periodically.
Therefore, there's no need to clear or manage retention.ms for the repartition topics.
Reference

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6150
Please leave a comment or correct this if I'm wrong.

Source:[Why retention.ms of Kaka Streams repartition topic is set to -1 by default? Isn't this infinitely retain messages in repartition topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65971984/why-retention-ms-of-kaka-streams-repartition-topic-is-set-to-1-by-default-isn?rq=1)